# Make [byteordermark] a synonym of [bom]

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

- The [byteordermark](/questions/tagged/byteordermark) tag currently has 11 tagged questions, compared to [bom](/questions/tagged/bom)'s 127.
- [bom](/questions/tagged/bom) already has a wiki entry; [byteordermark](/questions/tagged/byteordermark) has none.

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just retag those 11 questions and drop [byteordermark]? Anything against it?

Comment: Nothing against it. (Though I still think it would be a nice idea to set up a synonym.)

Comment: I dunno. Considering the fact that most questions already are tagged [bom] and of the ones who are tagged [byteordermark] most of them also have BOM in the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My preference would be to rename [byteordermark](/questions/tagged/byteordermark) to [byte-order-mark](/questions/tagged/byte-order-mark), and make [bom](/questions/tagged/bom) a synonym of [byte-order-mark](/questions/tagged/byte-order-mark). (Note: this requires moderator intervention.) Clarity trumps use count. [bom](/questions/tagged/bom) is clear in a context where Unicode is implied but is obscure on the scale of the big world of programming, [byte-order-mark](/questions/tagged/byte-order-mark) stands on its own.

Keep in mind that if someone wants to use [bom](/questions/tagged/bom) for some other purpose (we live in a world of TLAs), they will easily notice that they're using the wrong tag if it's rewritten to [byte-order-mark](/questions/tagged/byte-order-mark). Having the synonym in the other direction isn't helpful in this way.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. I'll wait until next week to see if there's any good arguments against, if not I'll fix it up. Remind me to revisit on Wednesday if it's not done by then :)

Comment: @Kev Come back Wednesday to check this out =)

Comment: I would rather see [bom] being used since that is what most people will refer to. Just check the amount of questions tagged bom and the amount of questions tagged byteordermark. IMHO in this specific case the TLA is justified.

Comment: @PeeHaa If someone types `bom` in the tag box they'll get the right tag. If someone sees `byte-order-mark` they'll understand what it's about. It's a win-win situation. Going by use count is usually the right thing when the two forms are about equally clear, but this isn't the case here.

Comment: @Kev Come back last Wednesday to check this out =)

Comment: It's now Wednesday evening and the tag synonym has been made.

Answer (score 2):

I would go the other way: Retag all [bom](/questions/tagged/bom) questions as [byteordermark](/questions/tagged/byteordermark).

[bom](/questions/tagged/bom) is ambiguous as it could mean "bill of materials".  Although it is not likely to be used this way on SO very often, it will confuse some programmers (those who work closely with electronic engineers for example.)

Comment: I agree, and I think @Gilles' answer covers this point already. I also like the recommendation of adding hyphens: `[byte-order-mark]`.